# Help understanding electromagnetism integral from exercise in MTW?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, classical-electrodynamics, maxwell-equations, variational-principle

I was skimming through Misner, Thorne and Wheeler's book *Gravitation* looking for exercises to challenge myself with and came across the following exercise on page 178:

> Verify that the variational principle $\delta I = 0$ gives Maxwell's equations by verifying $A_\mu$, and the Lorentz force law by varying $z^\mu(\tau)$, when 
>   \begin{equation}
> I = -\frac{1}{16\pi}\int F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} d^4 x + \frac{1}{2} m \int \frac{dz^\mu}{d\tau}\frac{dz_\mu}{d\tau}d\tau + e\int \frac{dz^\mu}{d\tau} A_\mu (z)d\tau
> \end{equation}
>   Here $F_{\mu\nu}$ is an abbreviation for $A_{\nu,\mu}-A_{\mu,\nu}$.

I don't understand what this integral represents. I recognize the Faraday tensor, although I don't know why there is a factor of $-\frac{1}{16\pi}$ there. It looked like an interesting problem, but I'd have to know what the terms are before I could tackle it.

**Could someone explain term by term what this integral stands for?**

Comment: The first term is the Maxwell Lagrangian (Lagrangian of the EM field), the second term is just the kinetic energy and the last is coupling of the potential to the particle.

Comment: More explicitly, the variational equation $$\frac{\delta I}{\delta z^\mu}=0$$ generates the Lorentz force law whereas $$\frac{\delta I}{\delta A^\mu}=0$$ generates (two of) Maxwell's equations with the current defined as $j^\mu=e\dot z^\mu$.

Comment: I'm curious...what equations did you obtain? I ask because the action I wrote down for this problem was $$S=-\frac{1}{4}\int d^4x \,F^2-m\int d\tau+e\int A_\mu dx^\mu$$ The $\pi$ is a strange convention that some people have, but your action has an extra factor of $1/4$...

Comment: I don't understand it either. Frankly, I am starting to question this book's editing. I found an exercise in the book to "prove the chain rule" for covariant derivatives, but it actually is the product rule, which seemed like a really sloppy error to me since they said "chain rule" several times not just once. Regarding this equation, if it had been 1/4, I wouldn't have been so confused because it would have looked like a normal classical electrodynamics Lagrangian, but with the 1/16, I wasn't sure. I have never seen the $\pi$ convention. I probably should have just asked about that part.

Comment: Huh, I've seen the chain rule called product rule before, but not the other way around. The $\pi$ convention is found in Wald, for example.

Comment: Yeah, here's the thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137420/verification-of-product-rule-for-covariant-derivatives-stuck-on-one-step-involv/1137459#1137459 I'm not sure if MTW are wrong or not, but the answerer seemed really confused why I was calling it the chain rule and I realized it wasn't the chain rule when he said that.

Comment: I just remembered you one asked a question about the current term in the Lagrangian density. Well look at the interaction term $$e\int A_\mu\dot z^\mu d\tau$$ Now a cool trick: $$e\int A_\mu\dot z^\mu d\tau=e\int d^4z \,\delta^4(z-z(\tau))\int \dot z^\mu A_\mu d\tau=\int A^\mu J_\mu\,d^4z$$ if we define $$J^\mu=e\delta^4(z-z(\tau))\int \dot z^\mu \,d\tau$$ Upon calculating the $\delta/\delta A^\mu$ variational integral, we see that a charged point particle creates an EM field because it generates a current.

Comment: Lol, that exercise looks horrible.

Comment: What is the difference between $I$ and $\mathbf{J}$? Like as I understand it, $\rho$ and $\mathbf{J}$ form a four vector $J^\alpha$. But I don't get what these represent or rather what context they are used in? For instance, $I$ is always a scalar quantity used in circuits. But what is $\mathbb{J}$ used for?

Comment: $$I=\iint\vec J\cdot d\vec S$$

Comment: Okay so for $$e\int A_\mu \dot{z}^\mu d\tau$$, why do we multiply by $e$? I just learned from looking at the Pauli equation that multiplying $e\phi$ converts potential back into units of energy so I was wondering if something similar was happening here.

Comment: $e$, the electric charge, is just the coupling constant of the current to the photon field. It's the same concept as $e\phi$, yes.